# Is there a way to iterate through hdfs dfs file system in unix to search for huge number of small files

Tags: shell, unix, hdfs

Need to iterate through hdfs dfs file system where the owner of the file system is my service account and find directories/folders where the number of small files are more than a lakh.

The problem I am facing is respect to the depths of these folders, for example:

- Path 1 : hdfs dfs edx/home/krn/zxy/
- Path 2 : hdfs dfs edx/home/nzy/

In Path 1 small files are present inside zxy which means the depth is 3 whereas for Path 2 small files are present in nzy which is of depth2.

I need help in write a bash/shell script where I can have the depth as dynamic and get all the locations/paths where there are > 100k small files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not understood globally